# dll инъекция в windows 8

Tags: c++, dll

Здравствуйте! Я так понял, что начиная с 8-ки dll инъекции нельзя делать, а есть этому альтернатива?

Comment: Наличие альтернативы зависит от того, зачем оно вам.

Comment: Может Вы слышали про [вот это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR#Microsoft_Windows) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все отлично делается! И на 8 и на 8.1 и на 10. Если нужен пример простой инъекции кода, могу помочь с кодом (обновлю сообщение).

> UPD

Способов загрузки dll превеликое множество, прочитать о них можно в книге Рихтера, вот один из простейших (работает на win8 100%, только для x86 приложений!!!):

```
bool load(const tstring & dllPath, const tstring & processName)
{
    // Получение дескриптора процесса
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, t_proc.getID(processName));
    if (process == NULL) {

        msg_er_full;
        return false;
    }
    //Из модуля kernel32.dll этого же процесса вытягиваем адрес функции LoadLibraryA
    LPVOID fp = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    if (fp == NULL) {

        msg_er_full;

        if (!CloseHandle(process))msg_er_full;

        return false;
    }
    // Выделение участка памяти размером dll_name для последующей записи в память процесса.
    LPVOID alloc{};
    if ((alloc = VirtualAllocEx(process, 0, dllPath.size(), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)) == NULL) {

        msg_er_full;

        if (!CloseHandle(process))msg_er_full;

        return false;
    }
    // Запись Dll в память
    if (WriteProcessMemory(process, alloc, dllPath.c_str(), dllPath.size(), 0) == NULL) {

        msg_er_full;

        if (!CloseHandle(process))msg_er_full;

        return false;
    }
    // Создание "удаленного" потока в адресном пространстве открытого процесса и последующая подгрузка нашей Dll
    if (CreateRemoteThread(process, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)fp, alloc, 0, 0) == NULL) {

        msg_er_full;

        if (!CloseHandle(process))msg_er_full;

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: А зачем загружать LoadLibrary через GetProcAddress? (Минус не мой.)

Comment: @VladD - я так понял, что автору нужна подгрузка dll из стороннего приложения в свое, с какой - то целью - я например таким образом пытаюсь "взломать" свое приложение (ищу баги и уязвимости)

Comment: А, и поэтому вы используете как можно меньше работы компилятора, понимаю.

Comment: @VladD - вы про это имели ввиду...

Comment: Ого, я думал на почту придет оповещение об ответе. Я сделал на 8, но на windows 10 почему то не работает, днем код приведу

Comment: @helldrg, код который я привел работает на XP, vista, 7, 8, 8.1,10.

Comment: Действительно, код работает, на всех windows только что проверял. В прошлый раз когда я задавал тему ничего не работало, странно
Спасибо всем, спасибо за комментарии в коде, у меня такой же примерно, но я не очень понимал как он производит инъекцию

Comment: @helldrg, пожалуйста!